# Twilio Application to call another person if one call fails

Tags: twilio

I am studying twilio's auto calling functionality for the one of our client.

Requirements:
We are handling software system of our client. And when ever there is error in
the system I need to call specific persons.

I could do above function easily on testing environment using php. But In actual scenario,
I want call on multiple number like if one person is not receiving call I must get call
on second number, third number and so on until one person receives call and understands error.

For the above functionality I have studied "Call Screening " example from site and also
communicate to support person but I didn't get exactly from the conversation.

When I call attempt_call.php from my browser I am getting xml output on browser only not any call.

Please guide me if any ready example is there that can solve my problem.

Thanks and best regards.
Piyush Merja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CallScreening didnt work for me..

I have called to one person and checked for its status if its completed then process terminated or continued to another person